# Touchpad drivers for Asus K501LB

Tags: touchpad, asus, focaltech

I'm looking for drivers for my touchpad on the Asus K501LB. I want the double-finger scroll function to work properly and other features available on Windows. Is there maybe another program for this I can install?

Ubuntu 15.04 with kernel 3.19.0-28-generic

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 FocalTech FocalTech Touchpad in mouse emulation mode id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam                     id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
[    0.210691] pnp: PnP ACPI init
[    0.210914] pnp 00:01: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs FLT0101 SYN0a00 SYN0002 PNP0f03 PNP0f13 PNP0f12 (active)
[    0.210948] pnp 00:02: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs ATK3001 PNP030b (active)
[    0.211067] pnp 00:04: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0b00 (active)
[    0.212169] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 8 devices
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput; dmesg | grep pnp` terminal command. And also specify Ubuntu and kernel version.

Comment: In addition to what @Pilot6 said, check "Additional Drivers". Just search for it in the dropdown. Is anything for your touchpad listed there?

Comment: You never can find any touchpad drivers there. @MichaelHoffmann

Comment: Oh. Good to know. Never mind, then. I'll bow out here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the driver. Run in terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/focaltech-dkms
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install focaltech-dkms
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
```

For Ubuntu 15.10+ Focaltech touchpads are supported by Ubuntu kernels.
There are no packages for Ubuntu 15.10+ in the PPA.

For Ubuntu 14.04 kernel 4.2 can be installed from Ubuntu repositories. You will need to remove `focaltech-dkms` and upgrade the kernel

```
sudo apt-get purge focaltech-dkms
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:hanipouspilot/focaltech-dkms
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily
```

Comment: This PPA is no longer available. Is there a mirror?

Comment: This PPA is not needed any more. Supported Ubuntu versions work with these touchpads.

Comment: I'm running Xubuntu 16.04, same device, and can't get the touchpad to support double finger scrolling as in the question. No option for it in the settings either [xinput](http://pastebin.com/Qt4k3FB4)

Comment: This is not the same device. This is a completely different touchpad. That is why I removed the PPA, because people think that it is a Focaltech for some reason.

Comment: For people who stumble upon this later, [this github repo](https://github.com/vlasenko/hid-asus-dkms) fixed the problem

Comment: I suggest writing a new question and an answer. It will be a good one. Lot's of people struggle with this issue. I planned to write one myself, but I do not have the hardware now.